# How does React i18next affect rendering performance?

Tags: performance, reactjs, i18next

How will [i18next](https://www.i18next.com/) affect rendring in React performance wise? And further, what about its interpolation mechanism vs the way react renders dynamic variables?

#### Given the following

**/locales/{language}/common.json**:

```
{
    "hello-world": "Hello, World",
    "interpolated": "Hello, {{ name }}"
}
```

**Example with i18next**

```
// Import i18n config and translate function
const Example = function(ownProps) {
  { t } = ownProps; 
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{ t('interpolated', { name: "World" }) }</h1>
      <h1>{ t('hello-world') }</h1>
    </div>
  );
};

export default translate('common', { i18n })(Example);
```

**Example without i18next**

```
const Example = function() {
  let name = "World";
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Hello, World</h1>
      <h1>Hello, { name }</h1>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Example;
```

How much difference for the lookups:

- `t('interpolated', { name: "World" })` vs `Hello, { name }`
- `t('hello-world')` vs `Hello, World`

Comment: Probably negligible if you follow best practices. Don't worry about performance unless you're running into performance issues. Follow best practices, and optimise if need be. It's a pretty silly thing to worry about performance over.

Comment: agree with @AdamLeBlanc we did not had any significant (noticable) performance impacts when using i18next.

Comment: @AdamLeBlanc Yeah it's pretty silly for the example provided here, but if one were to have lots of react componentes, lots of namespaces and lots of interpolation I thought that one might notice a difference in the rendring time. However, as you state it should not be a problem if I follow best practises. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe everything is optimized now but this repo used to show some performance problems.

https://github.com/beheh/react-i18next-performance